# New Processor Orange Light Of Death

Tags: windows, dell-dimension

I just bought a Quad Core Processor to replace my Dual core. I just got my package and I put it in to test it and then was going to take it out cause I don't have any usable Thermal Paste right now. But when I turn it on it give me a steady orange power button light. So I put in my old CPU powers on correctly. I even took out all but 2 GB of ram thinking I might have gotten a 32-Bit processor.

Here's my specs

Dell Dimension E521
8 GB RAM
Socket Type AM2
CPU: AMD Athlon x64 Dual Core 1.9 GHz

New CPU Socket Type AM2
New CPU: AMD Opteron Quad Core 2.1 GHZ

I made sure no pins were bent

Problem: OLOD With New Processor, computer does not boot into bios or windows.

Question: How to fix the problem.

Comment: I would be surprised if the E521 supports the Opteron processors, although I can't find a compatibility list on my phone, just because the socket is the same doesn't mean the bios or chipset support it.

Comment: So BIOS update?

Comment: is there an update available? If so, do it... Also check the owner or service manual, it should have a list of supported processors,  again, I doubt that board is capable of running an Opteron processor.

Comment: "might have gotten a 32-Bit processor." = Even if you did, if the motherboard supports the CPU, it would work.  **All 64-bit processors are x86 processors.**

Comment: Mobo doesn't support it, was hoping it would cause I needed the upgrade

Comment: Thanks for trying to close the loop on your question.  Super User does this a little different from the way forums typically do.  Rather than adding "solved" to the title and posting a comment, post your own answer.  That will allow future readers to search for and find the answer.  In another day (two days after posting the question), you will be able to accept your answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, which will indicate the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MotherBoard Didn't support the Processor